# How to use ZWAMP

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I am newbie to ZWAMP server. I like to ask how to use ZWAMP server. I download and install the ZWAMP package, but i dont have idea how to use it.

I google it, but dont get any information, can someone help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost 4 months Z-WAMP developers updates the pages and hekp support.
Now it will info available on [this](http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/)

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. At best it should be a comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got IIS or some other web server stuck on your machine you can change the Apache port to a different number which was stopping mine from working. Right click the system tray icon, then Configuration -> Apache Main.

Change the following lines to something like:

```
ServerName localhost:81
Listen 81
```

Then right click the system tray icon again and click 'Restart'.

You can now browse to `http://localhost:81` and it should work. To edit the web files they're in:

```
installation_directory\vdrive\web\
```